# Transform tidy dataframe into form for sparklines (dataui)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some tidy data and need to transform it into a format that works for building small graphs (sparklines) using the `dataui` package. You can see the required dataframe format in the code example below, `df_sparkline`.

The tidy data I have has about 30 companies and a year of data which is < 10,000 rows. What is the best (clearest to understand is valued more than raw speed) way to transform df_tidy to df_sparklines?

```
library("dataui")
library("reactable")
library("tidyverse")

df_tidy <- tibble(
  company = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
  line_data = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1),
  date = c(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-01-02"), as.Date("2021-01-02"), as.Date("2021-01-03"), as.Date("2021-01-03"))
)

df_sparkline <- structure(list(company = c("A", "B"), line_data = list(list(c(1, 2, 1)), list(c(2, 2, 1)))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

rt1 <- reactable(
  df_sparkline,
  columns = list(
    line_data = colDef(
      cell = function(value, index) {
        dui_sparkline(
          data = value[[1]], 
          height = 80,
          components = dui_sparklineseries(curve = "linear") # https://github.com/williaster/data-ui/tree/master/packages/sparkline#series
        )
      }
    )
  )
)
rt1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is `group_by()` and `summarise()`:

```
df_sparkline2 = df_tidy %>% 
  group_by(company) %>% 
  summarise(line_data=list(list(line_data)))

waldo::compare(df_sparkline, df_sparkline2)
# √ No differences
```

The key here is to call `list()` inside `summarise()`.